# Azure AD authentication and relationships with user

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I have a very simple net core application with only available authentication method is Azure AD. I don't have any local accounts and I don't want any other authentication mechanism other than Azure AD.

But I want to be able to see when and who created / modified any record. So I need relationships between all of my tables and my users. But I can't do that because when using Azure AD authentication I don't have any tables that holds user information.

For this, I extended IdentityUser, just to see if it is filling any data in (at least) AspNetUserLogins table when a user is authenticated through Azure AD but of course it doesn't do it.

What is the best way to tackle this?

Should I create a table that holds information of a user's name, email address, objectId, check for any changes from Azure to name and email address every time user logs in? And then create relationship between tables using another meta table?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any update on it?

Answer (score 1):

For Azure AD authentication, it will allow you to use microsoft account(xx@yy.onmicrosoft.com) to sign in your application, so that you don't need to set up user management module in your application. Hence, it will provide you the feature to read user information.

In your requirement, you need to see when/who modify any records. Per my understanding, you should have a table which may containing following columns: `id(primary key), operation_type, operation_target, timestamp, user_id...` so that you can know who did some operation on some pages. It's necessary for you to get the user information before you insert the row. After users sign in application, you can use `var user = HttpContext.User.Identity;` in the Contorller to get user information.

[image]

If you had a requirement to show operation details contained user detailed information. When you have a user table in your database, you can query record table alone with the user table, but when you use AAD, there's no user table. So when you need to query user details, you should use Ms graph api to query user information. Like [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/Controllers/HomeController.cs):

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
}

currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll create another table and fill it with user actions. I can get a lot of information about a user through "Optional Claims" from Azure AD but thanks for the extra Graph information though, I'll definitely need it :)

Comment: sounds like you've got the idea. thanks for your reply then : )